# Reverse items in LongListSelector C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have items in an `ObservableCollection` bound to a `LongListSelector` on a WindowsPhone8 app.

This is how I bind to the `LongListSelector`:

```xml
<phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-12,0" x:Name="MainLongListSelector" SelectionChanged="MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Posts}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserDisplayName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Is there a way to have the order reversed in the XAML, rather than having to reverse the `ObservableCollection` backing it?

Comment: I think you're looking for `CollectionViewSource` - that lets you sort/group/filter without changing the underlying collection.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you want to reverse the Item of collection you can use the Reverse method by reversing the order of the elements in it.

Regards.

Comment: Yeah, but that is on the `Collection` backing the `LongListSelector` , what I am looking for is something that can reverse it on the presentation side i.e. `XAML`